# Implicit object works inline but not when it is imported

Tags: scala, avro4s

I am using `avro4s` to help with avro serialization and deserialization.

I have a case class that includes `Timestamp`s and need those `Timestamp`s to be converted to nicely formatted strings before I publish the records to Kafka; the default encoder is converting my `Timestamp`s to `Long`s. I read that I needed to write a decoder and encoder (from the `avro4s` readme).

Here is my case class:

```
case class MembershipRecordEvent(id: String,
                                 userHandle: String,
                                 planId: String,
                                 teamId: Option[String] = None,
                                 note: Option[String] = None,
                                 startDate: Timestamp,
                                 endDate: Option[Timestamp] = None,
                                 eventName: Option[String] = None,
                                 eventDate: Timestamp)
```

I have written the following encoder:

`Test.scala`

```
def test() = {
implicit object MembershipRecordEventEncoder extends Encoder[MembershipRecordEvent] {
  override def encode(t: MembershipRecordEvent, schema: Schema) = {
    val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    val record = new GenericData.Record(schema)
    record.put("id", t.id)
    record.put("userHandle", t.userHandle)
    record.put("teamId", t.teamId.orNull)
    record.put("note", t.note.orNull)
    record.put("startDate", dateFormat.format(t.startDate))
    record.put("endDate", if(t.endDate.isDefined) dateFormat.format(t.endDate.get) else null)
    record.put("eventName", t.eventName.orNull)
    record.put("eventDate", dateFormat.format(t.eventDate))
    record
    }
  }

val recordInAvro2 = Encoder[MembershipRecordEvent].encode(testRecord, AvroSchema[MembershipRecordEvent]).asInstanceOf[GenericRecord]
    println(recordInAvro2)
}
```

If I declare the my `implicit object` in line, like I did above, it creates the `GenericRecord` that I am looking for just fine. I tried to abstract the `implicit object` to a file, wrapped in an object, and I `import Implicits._` to use my custom encoder.

`Implicits.scala`

```
object Implicits {
implicit object MembershipRecordEventEncoder extends Encoder[MembershipRecordEvent] {
  override def encode(t: MembershipRecordEvent, schema: Schema) = {
    val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    val record = new GenericData.Record(schema)
    record.put("id", t.id)
    record.put("userHandle", t.userHandle)
    record.put("teamId", t.teamId.orNull)
    record.put("note", t.note.orNull)
    record.put("startDate", dateFormat.format(t.startDate))
    record.put("endDate", if(t.endDate.isDefined) dateFormat.format(t.endDate.get) else null)
    record.put("eventName", t.eventName.orNull)
    record.put("eventDate", dateFormat.format(t.eventDate))
    record
    }
  }
}
```

`Test.scala`

```
import Implicits._
val recordInAvro2 = Encoder[MembershipRecordEvent].encode(testRecord, AvroSchema[MembershipRecordEvent]).asInstanceOf[GenericRecord]
    println(recordInAvro2)
```

It fails to use my encoder (doesn't hit my breakpoints). I have tried a myriad of things to try and see why it fails to no avail.

How can I correctly import an implicit object?

Is there a simpler solution to encode my `case class`'s `Timestamp`s to `String`s without writing an encoder for the entire `case class`?

Comment: What do you mean by "implicit object in line"? What is the name of the new file? What is the path of that file? What is the content of that file? What is the import line you are using that is failing?

Comment: Try to move encoder to companion object of MembershipRecordEvent. As the rule of thumb you should put instances of typeclasses to companion object of class.

Comment: What version are you using? The code doesn't look like 3 or 4.

Comment: Looks like `avro4s-core_2.11`.

Comment: Are you saying it compiles? If it compiles it is finding the implicit. What may happen is the implicit value is null.

Comment: @pedrofurla Yes it does compile but does not hit any of my breakpoints in my implementation of Encoder. And yes, you are correct, I am on 2.11

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik This did the trick! Though, I don't know why Scala couldn't find my Encoder. The IntelliJ tooling told me that my import was being used. 

Anyways, if you put your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Your import is being used. It is some object initialization problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR

As suggested in one of the comments above, you can place it in the companion object.

The longer version:

Probably you have another encoder, that is used instead of the encoder you defined in `Implicits`.

I'll quote some phrases from [WHERE DOES SCALA LOOK FOR IMPLICITS?](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html)

> When a value of a certain name is required, lexical scope is searched for a value with that name. Similarly, when an implicit value of a certain type is required, lexical scope is searched for a value with that type.
>
> Any such value which can be referenced with its “simple” name, without selecting from another value using dotted syntax, is an eligible implicit value.
> There may be more than one such value because they have different names.
>
> In that case, overload resolution is used to pick one of them. The algorithm for overload resolution is the same used to choose the reference for a given name, when more than one term in scope has that name. For example, println is overloaded, and each overload takes a different parameter type. An invocation of println requires selecting the correct overloaded method.
>
> In implicit search, overload resolution chooses a value among more than one that have the same required type. Usually this entails selecting a narrower type or a value defined in a subclass relative to other eligible values.
>
> The rule that the value must be accessible using its simple name means that the normal rules for name binding apply.
>
> In summary, a definition for x shadows a definition in an enclosing scope. But a binding for x can also be introduced by local imports. Imported symbols can’t override definitions of the same name in an enclosing scope. Similarly, wildcard imports can’t override an import of a specific name, and names in the current package that are visible from other source files can’t override imports or local definitions.
>
> These are the normal rules for deciding what x means in a given context, and also determine which value x is accessible by its simple name and is eligible as an implicit.
>
> This means that an implicit in scope can be disabled by shadowing it with a term of the same name.

Now I'll state the companion object logic:

> Implicit syntax can avoid the import tax, which of course is a “sin tax,” by leveraging “implicit scope”, which depends on the type of the implicit instead of imports in lexical scope.
>
> When an implicit of type T is required, implicit scope includes the companion object T:
> When an F[T] is required, implicit scope includes both the companion of F and the companion of the type argument, e.g., object C for F[C].
>
> In addition, implicit scope includes the companions of the base classes of F and C, including package objects, such as p for p.F.